# Is it safe to publish a @NotThreadSafe instance that was constructed without holding the lock used to publish?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Is this a safe publication?

Given the class:

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class Pub {
   int drinkers;
   public Pub(int drinkers) {
      this.drinkers = drinkers;
   }
}
```

T1 invokes `publish()` and T2 invokes `inspect`:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

@GuardedBy("lock")
private Pub shared;

void publish() {
  Pub p = new Pub(12);
  synchronized(lock) {
      this.shared = p;  // publish  
  }
}

Pub inspect() {
  synchronized(lock) {
     return shared;
  }
}
```

Is T2 guaranteed to see that `shared.drinkers == 12`?   Or was the fact that we did not *construct* the Pub while holding the lock constitute an unsafe publication?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete code in original question ... all fixed now.

Comment: It's safe. You should make the lock final though.

Comment: @JBNizet I fixed my lock, thanks.  Why would T2 never see `shared.drinkers == 0`?

Comment: Because there is a happens-before guarantee between two instructions of the same thread (so the assignment of drinkers happens before the assignment of shared in T1), and there is also a happens-before guarantee between an unlock and a lock of the same monitor (so the write of shared in T1 happens before the read of shared by T2). Since happens-before is transitive, the assignment to drinkers in T1 happens before the read of shared in T2. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid operation. Pub will either be null or initialised properly. This is because initialisation and assignment happen after each other on the same thread.

Comment: Yes, but thread T1 makes an assignment to `drinkers` while the lock is not held.  Is the value of `drinkers` propagated to T2 just because we synchronized when we set the value of `shared`?

Comment: Non-final fields aren't guaranteed to be set when the constructor is called - the assignment can be delayed. The question is whether the assignment will happen before the later synchronization.

Comment: You never"synchronise". By using the synchronized keyword you simply define blocks that are guaranteed to be entered by only one threadat a time.

Comment: @sorencito The lightbulb is nearly on.  So in terms of the ordering of work done by a thread, this would work too?  `void publish() { Pub p = new Pub(12); this.shared = p;  synchronized(lock) {} }`.  Once I release the lock, other threads acquiring it can see everything I did prior to *releasing it*.  Because all I'm doing here is blindly setting a single value, that's all fine.  If I actually wanted to see the results of what other threads had done, and prevent them from changing it while I perform work, then I need to *acquire* the lock and do work while holding it.  Yes?

Comment: Well, not really, no. I think you confuse something. You never have the need to do anything like releasing a lock for other threads to "see"something. In synchronized blocks it is rather about what other states of manipulation of shared information other threads may NOT see. It's all about avoiding funny effects like some thread seeing half an assignment (suppose this could happen in a64 bit environment) of this.shared. What you want to do is ensure that while #publish is running on T1, T2 does not see corrupt states of shared when calling #inspect.

Comment: @DavidBullock: The problem with this way of doing is that T2 might read the `shared` variable before T1 synchronizes on `lock`, and see 0 in `shared.drinkers` instead of 12, because `drinkers` is not final.

Comment: @sorencito: synchronized is also used to provide visibility guarantees, in addition to mutual exclusion. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Comment: JB Nizet is of course right - you need the synchronization on the same monitor in order to guarantee visibility. Anyway, I just wanted to avoid the impression that having the lock is something like committing into a database. It is much more subtle. Misunderstanding if that point was already clear.

Comment: Thanks to both.  My brain is mush, and I have to go to bed!  I will come back to this soon.

Comment: OK, I've got it now.  Understanding 'happens before' is the key. When T1 writes first to `drinkers` and then to `shared`, both of these actually happen, in that order ... as far as T1 is concerned.  However, until T2 acquires the same object monitor that T1 has released, there is no guarantee that T2 will see either the write to `drinkers` or the write to `shared` ... and if it does see these writes, they aren't guaranteed to be in any particular order.  My first #publish method is safe publication, because T2 can't read `shared` until T1 releases the monitor and all its work is now 'visible'.